# Can you send data from asp.net web api or web service to a web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, asmx

Is it possible to redirect from a web api or asmx web service to a web form along with sending data to the web form? I can't use a query string because its sensitive data.

Comment: You would likely want  some kind of authentication on form load, and then fetch the sensitive data after authentication is verified.  BUT, it's difficult to give a more specific answer when your question is rather general.

Comment: Doesn't matter whom are you sending data to webform or webservice the data will be going through network the same way.

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing any architecture where a user starts by consuming a web service and ends up on a web form. What is that user experience like? (Or did you mean something else, e.g. populate a web form with data retrieved from a web api?)